# Discount,Rating Filler navigation in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have requirement to display discount percentage,rating  on navigation filler in magneto.

please give any idea or suggestion for this.

or please share link if have free magneto extension.

my requirement is like below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute `discount` of type `dropdown`. use the attribute in layred navigation `filterable with results`.

Create two options for the attribute `0-50`& `50 & above`.

And assign to relevant attribute set. And select the range on which particular products fall on editing/adding products.